# SQLite phonebook insert failing

Tags: ios, sqlite

In the code below, the commented-out code works.

But using the `saveData` method of the `DBMgr` Class results in "Failded to add contact".

I want to see "Contact added" instead.

```
-(void) saveData{    
    NSString *insSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO CONTACTS (name,address,phone) VALUES (\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")",name.text,address.text,phone.text];

     DBMgr *dbmgr = [DBMgr alloc];

     if([dbmgr saveData:insSQL]== 0){
     status.text = @"Contact added";
     }else if([dbmgr saveData:insSQL]== 1){
     status.text=@"Failded to add contact";
     }

    /*sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO CONTACTS (name,address,phone) VALUES (\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")",name.text,address.text,phone.text];

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);

        if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            status.text = @"Contact added";
            name.text = @"";
            address.text = @"";
            phone.text = @"";
        }else{
            status.text=@"Failded to add contact";
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(contactDB);

    }*/
}

-(NSInteger) saveData:(NSString *) querySQL{
    NSInteger result;
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *insertSQL = querySQL;

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

        sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);

        if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            result = 0;
        }else{
            result = 1;
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(contactDB);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I don't know what the `DBMgr` class is but perhaps you need to do `DBMgr *dbmgr = [[DBMgr alloc] init];` instead of just `alloc`.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the result codes of *all* of your SQLite calls, and if they fail, log the error:

```
- (NSInteger) saveData:(NSString *) querySQL{
    NSInteger result = 1;
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *insertSQL = querySQL;

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSLog(@"%s: prepare failed: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(contactDB));
        else
        {
            if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                result = 0;
            }else{
                NSLog(@"%s: step failed: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(contactDB));
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }

        sqlite3_close(contactDB);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%s: open failed", __FUNCTION__);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Unless you look at `sqlite3_errmsg`, you're just guessing. And check `sqlite3_prepare_v2` return code, too, like I did above, (as that will more likely be the initial indication of a problem).

---

Two other, unrelated, observations:

1. The `DBMgr` should be initialized, e.g.:

   ```
   DBMgr *dbmgr = [[DBMgr alloc] init];
   ```
2. You are building your `INSERT` statement using `stringWithFormat`. That's very dangerous, you should use `?` placeholders in your SQL:

   ```
   const char *insSQL = "INSERT INTO CONTACTS (name,address,phone) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
   sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insSQL, -1, &statement, NULL);
   ```

   Then, after preparing that statement, you should then use the [`sqlite3_bind_text`](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) function to assign your values to those three placeholders, e.g.

   ```
   sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [name.text    UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
   sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [address.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
   sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [phone.text   UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
   ```

   By the way, if you wanted to specify `NULL`, you'd call `sqlite3_bind_null` instead of `sqlite3_bind_text`.

   Obviously, check the return code from each of those to make sure you returned `SQLITE_OK` for each, again, logging `sqlite3_errmsg` if it failed.

   I appreciate that this change is going to require some refactoring of your code, but it's important to use `sqlite3_bind_text` to avoid SQL injection attacks and errors that will result if the user typed in a value that included quotation marks.

By the way, if you're looking at the above and realizing that it takes a lot of code to do this properly, you might want to consider using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) which can significantly simplify your life.

Comment: thx!!  
 i solve the problem!!!!!  

cause is..<br/><br/>

`-(void) initDB:(NSString *)dbPath:(sqlite3 *)contDB{<br/>
    self.databasePath = dbPath;<br/>
    self.contactDB = contDB;<br/>
}`

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem. BTW, don't forget to call `[super init]`.